# Google Maps return city in cyrillic

Tags: google-maps

I would like to translate some cities from latin into cyrillic and would like to use Google Maps.

I am trying in this way:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Moskau&sensor=false&hl=ru&oe=utf-8

The problem is I am getting the response only in latin. How is it possible to become the result in cyrillic?

Comment: Your link gives me cyrillic names: "long_name" : "Москва"

Comment: Hmm how is this possible. I am calling the api from Germany. What need I to change to become it in cyrillic?

Comment: Maybe in this way: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Moskau&sensor=false&hl=ru&oe=utf-8&language=ru

Comment: Yes, exactly. more info here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `language` parameter:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Moskau&sensor=false&oe=utf-8&language=ru