# Google geocode returning in Cyrillic

Tags: google-maps, google-api, geocoding

Is there any way to get informations from geocode in latin. I have tried with language parameter but with no success. Link is:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.836009,20.5078136&sensor=false&oe=utf-8&language=en
```

[link](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.836009,20.5078136&sensor=false&oe=utf-8&language=en)

Comment: IIRC the parameter is named `hl` not `language` (Edit ah, apparently not: [Google Maps return city in cyrillic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14070301)

Comment: Try without `oe=utf-8`. `language=en` is correct for language setting

Comment: i tried but it is not working and hl is not wokring to..

Comment: You may assume that these details are not available in english when you've set the language-parameter to `en` and the result isn't in english

Comment: This is then really bad because the streets in serbia are named in latin not cyrillic. Shame on Google.